# Transitions in an event-driven Finite State Machine

Tags: python, transition, state-machine, event-driven

I'm using [Transitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions) in python for implement a finite state machine event driven.

I want to implement a FSM where the transition are triggered by an event that is processed by avoiding a if/elif statement.

For example: I have a simple FSM of a lamp, if it came (in a non-deterministic way) the `'goInlampOn'` event we move to the 'on' state, if the `'goInlampOff'` event arrives we move to the `'off'` state.

So my question is:

**Is there a way to create a method called `process_event(event)` in the FSM class that process each event with the logic of my FSM without using a very long (not in this very simple case) if-elif statement?**

Here's an example of the code:

```
class MyFsm(object):

    transitions = [
        {'trigger': 'switchOff', 'source':'on', 'dest':'off'},
        {'trigger': 'switchOn', 'source':'off', 'dest':'on'}
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        ''' initialating the FSM '''
        self.machine = Machine(model=self, states=self.states,
                               transitions=self.transitions, initial='on')
        on = On()
        off = Off()
        self.machine.add_state(off)
        self.machine.add_state(on)

    # A SMART SOLUTION TO IMPLEMENT THIS METHOD WITHOUT USING
    # if state == off: ... elif state==on...
    def process_event(self,event):

         if self.state == 'off':
             if event == 'goInlampOn':
                 self.switchOn()

         elif self.state == 'on':
             if event == 'goInlampOff':
                 self.switchOff()
```

in the case that I presented there are only 2 states, but if I had 10 or 15?
I tried to implement the solution that I think @aleneum has suggested to me. in this solution, however, I have to record twice the transitions of my state machine.
it's correct ? could there be a better solution (avoiding writing the transitions twice)?
this is a state machine with 4 state ( A, B, C, D) the only transitions permitted are:
1. A->B
2. B->C
3. C->D
4. D->A
5. C->A
here the code:

```
from transitions import Machine
from states import A,B,C,D
class MyFsm(object):

transitions = [
    {'trigger': 'go_in_B_fromA','source':'A','dest':'B'},
    {'trigger': 'go_in_C_fromB','source':'B','dest':'C'},
    {'trigger': 'go_in_D_fromC','source':'C','dest':'D'},
    {'trigger': 'go_in_A_fromD','source':'D','dest':'A'},
    {'trigger': 'go_in_A_fromC','source':'C','dest':'A'},        
    {'trigger': 'go_in_B_fromA','source':['C','D','B'],'dest':None},
    {'trigger': 'go_in_C_fromB','source':['C','D','A'],'dest':None},
    {'trigger': 'go_in_D_fromC','source':['B','D','A'],'dest':None},
    {'trigger': 'go_in_A_fromD','source':['B','A','C'],'dest':None},
    {'trigger': 'go_in_A_fromC','source':['D','A','B'],'dest':None}
]

def __init__(self):   
    self.machine = Machine(model=self, states = self.states ,transitions= self.transitions, initial = 'A' )       
    a = A()
    b = B()
    c = C()
    d = D()       
    self.machine.add_state(a)
    self.machine.add_state(b)
    self.machine.add_state(c)
    self.machine.add_state(d)


def process_event(self,event):   

    if event == 'go_in_B_fromA' :
        self.go_in_B_fromA()

    if event == 'go_in_C_fromB' :
        self.go_in_C_fromB()

    if event == 'go_in_D_fromC' :
        self.go_in_D_fromC()

    if event == 'go_in_A_fromD' :
        self.go_in_A_fromD()

    if event == 'go_in_A_fromC' :
        self.go_in_A_fromC()

'''my main is something like this'''
myfsm = MyFsm()
while True:
    event = event_from_external_bahaviour()
    myfsm.process_event(event)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how FSMs work. You shouldn't need to have a `process_event()` method like that. There should be separate states in the machine representing (in this case) being On or Off. It's the `transitions` table that determines, in a data-driven way, what happens when different events occur with respect to the current state of the machine.

Comment: You can set methods that will be run on any state change using the keywords 'before_state_change` or `after_state_change` in your `Machine()` initialization. The details are in the link you posted.

Comment: is it possible to implement this table without a long if-elif or switch statement? I said long in the case that it has many states and transitions

Comment: yes, all the methods and the logic is encapsulate in each state, but how can i move from a state to another state when an event occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @martineau, the effect of events/the behaviour of the model should be determined by its current state. Large blocks of if/then statements is actually what you want to avoid by using state machines.
Have a look at the following code snippet:

```
from transitions.core import Machine, State, MachineError

class On(State):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(On, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Off(State):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Off, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class MyFsm(object):

    transitions = [
        {'trigger': 'switchOff', 'source':'on', 'dest':'off'},
        {'trigger': 'switchOn', 'source':'off', 'dest':'on'}
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        # ignore_invalid_triggers will allow to process events not defined for a state
        on = On(name='on', ignore_invalid_triggers=True)
        off = Off(name='off', ignore_invalid_triggers=False)
        self.machine = Machine(model=self, states=[on, off], transitions=self.transitions, initial='on')

machine = MyFsm()
print(machine.state)  # >>> on
machine.switchOff()
print(machine.state)  # >>> off
try:
    # this will raise a MachineException because there is no transition 'switchOff'
    # defined in state 'off'
    machine.switchOff()  # raises MachineException
    raise Exception("This exception will not be raised")
except MachineError:
    pass
print(machine.state)  # >>> off
machine.switchOn()
print(machine.state)  # >>> on
# this will NOT raise an Exception since we configured 'on'
# to ignore transitions not defined for this state
machine.switchOn()
print(machine.state)  # >>> on
```

I defined some placeholder classes for `On` and `Off` since I assume you want to use custom state classes. `transitions` enables you to just trigger the model's method without keeping track of the current state. Your configuration will determine what will happen. Depending on your needs you can raise `MachineError` if a method is triggered which is not defined for your state.
Considering your example, I would suggest to just ignore invalid triggers since the attempt to switch a lamp on or off twice is not a big deal.
Another solution would be to 'loop' states or use [internal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Internal_transitions) transitions if you want to avoid invalid triggers:

```
# leaves and enters state off even if its already off
# processes all on_enter/exit callbacks
{'trigger': 'switchOff', 'source':['on', 'off'], 'dest':'off'}

# an internal transition is defined by having dest set to 'None'
# processes no state callbacks
{'trigger': 'switchOff', 'source': 'off', 'dest': None}
```

It highly depends on your use case and the system you actually control with this state machine which behaviour is to be preferred.

Comment: I followed your advice (adding internal transitions) in a more complex state machine. I reported the code in my initial question, is that correct?

Comment: You can also pass strings directly with `self.trigger('go_in_B_fromA')`. Considering comprehensibility of your code, I'd still prefer `ignore_invalid_triggers=True` since it reduces the configuration complexity by a huge margin.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understand your question since the very point of using a library like transitions is to avoid writing long `if`-`else if` chains.  Moreover, the documentation never mentions that you should reimplement `process_event()`.

So I can only paraphrase the documentation to transitions with your example and no `ifs`. I hope that it helps you.

```
from transitions import Machine


class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.machine = Machine(
            model=self,
            states=["on", "off"],
            transitions=[
                {
                    "trigger": "switchOff",
                    "source": "on",
                    "dest": "off",
                },
                {
                    "trigger": "switchOn",
                    "source": "off",
                    "dest": "on",
                },
            ],
            initial="on",
            ignore_invalid_triggers=True,
        )


m = Model()
assert m.state == "on"

# We are in state 'on' and there is not 'switchOn'
# transition defined: nothing happens.
#
# Without `ignore_invalid_triggers`, transitions
# would raise an exception.
m.switchOn()
assert m.state == "on"

# We still are in 'on' and 'switchOff' brings
# us to 'off.
m.switchOff()
assert m.state == "off"
```

You may consider reading the wikipedia article on UML state machines for example as transitions comes fairly close to implementing it.